# Launch browser with --option

Tags: browser

In order to use the [remote debugging](http://www.webkit.org/blog/1620/webkit-remote-debugging/) WebKit's feature, I'd like to launch android's browser (from emulator) with the `--remote-debugging-port` option.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you can't launch an APK with arguments of that sort.  The comments on the page you link to seem to indicate that it's not supported on Android, as well.  I find it odd that the instructions appear to be specifically for Chromium if it was meant to work on all WebKit browsers.